# APIGateway Lambda integration do not serve binary file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an api rest gateway and a lambda fetching an image from s3 after doing some checks.

That serving binary files is not so easy I noticed and found a lot of problems about this topic on SO or on other sites.

What I understand and already configured is the following:

- my lambda is returning an JSON object with `isBase64Encoded`

```js
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": mimeType, // mimeType is here image/jpeg
  },
  body: data.toString("base64"), // data is a buffer;
  // I also tried data.toString("binary") and data.toString()
  isBase64Encoded: true,
}
```

In my API gateway I set the binary Media Types to the following

```
Resources:
  MyApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      ...
      BinaryMediaTypes:
        - "application/octet"
        - "image/jpeg"
        - "image/png"
        - "image/gif"
        - "image/*"
```

This settings I see also in the AWS Console.

When I now query me API Gateway I only receive a BASE64 encoded image.

```sh
❯ curl https://myurl/test/profile-picture?size=small  -H "Accept: image/jpeg" -v 

* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to xxx port 443 (#0)
...
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x558f76b7fea0)
> GET /test/profile-picture?size=small HTTP/2
> Host: xxx
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: image/jpeg
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Sun, 28 Feb 2021 21:37:04 GMT
< content-type: image/jpeg
< content-length: 3940
< x-amzn-requestid: bc54ee15-5c41-4828-a7b2-c4978af07176
< x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-603c0d00-2f468936671986a95532641e;Sampled=0
< 
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* Connection #0 to host xn5gb6d7e6.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com left intact
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
```

Is there something wrong?
I am not able to figre the error out :-(

Comment: Can you try with `BinaryMediaTypes` of `*/* `?

Comment: Are you use `serverless` framework?

Comment: @Marcin there is no difference at all.

Comment: @hoangdv no, the AWS resources are setup with AWS SAM and Cloudformation

Comment: Check again in aws console, make sure binary media type is set. https://codetheworld.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/apigateway_setting.png